# Why SetPixel is not precise? How to apply float to integer? Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, precision, pixel, floating-accuracy

I am using Shader that let me make holes in my textures. I use TextCoord from Raycast to chose places where should be holes. Next, I am using SetPixel32 to make a hole. Unfortunately every version of SetPixel doesn't let me to use floats from TextCoord, so my holes aren't precise. I need very much precise holes where I clicked. You can see that on picture. Could anyone explain to me why SetPixel don't let me to use float value? How can I workaround to get precise result in need? I am sure it's int/float problem, every other part of script works propertly.
[image]

Comment: Please add meaningful code. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confused on how `SetPixel()` works. It gets its coordinates from the Texture2D where every unit is a pixel wide. So the reason it doesn't use floats is because there are no half pixels, only whole pixels which is why there are no methods that take in float values. If you are having trouble getting the correct coordinates, perhaps you are not sending in the correct values to the function.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure I'm sending correct values, I took example from Unity Docs. So I think I should use a bigger texture resolution to get more detailed effect? Is it good way? What about efficiency?

Comment: Assuming you are using a mesh collider, is it convex or concave? I believe you might want to make sure that it is concave and that convex is not checked.

Comment: It's concave, ofcourse. My only problem is with float precision. I made a test: changed X,Y values about +1 or -1. My hole never was perfect in my raycast hit coords.

Comment: What I'm saying is even if you get a value of 1.5 and 6.8 out of a 10x10 coordinate system is that it will only give you whole pixels not anything less. For example, it will give you the pixel spanning from 1 to 2 and 6 to 7 which will include the previous example coordinates. If you don't like how casting works you can try a Rounding function? Or try a greater resolution as mentioned earlier.